# Routing or redirecting partial path in API gateway proxy to Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have an implementation of `API Gateway` as proxy to a `Lambda` function (which is the one that returns the statusCode and payload)

The invokation url is something like:

https://5656tre23.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev

I have the following path: `/book/${some-uuid}`

Full URL: https://5656tre23.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/book/${some-uuid}

I also created a custom domain: `api.mydomain.com/` which resolves to `https://5656tre23.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/`

If I pass the full path, it works with both, regular Api Gateway URL and with the custom domain. Example: 
`api.mydomain.com/book/${some-uuid}`

However, if the I enter:

- https://5656tre23.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev
- https://5656tre23.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/book

I receive the following message

```
{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}
```

What I want, if the I go to:

- /dev
- /dev/book
- or anything else than `https://5656tre23.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/book/${some-uuid}` redirect to `mydomain.com`

I will appreciate help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some sort of authentication setup? Like catapult?

If so, you will need to add all of your endpoints to that policy in order to access them.
Check out: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/control-access-to-your-apis-using-amazon-api-gateway-resource-policies/

Comment: It's better to leave some code to explain rather than a link since it may become invalid